# Echo number of rows where id=$id

Tags: php, mysql, echo, rows

I've tried to echo number of rows where a certain id=$id. This is essentially to count the number of "votes" a person has been receiving on the website. It works like a charm in mysqlworkbench, however the number of rows where this person's id has been inserted into database (through the voting button) won't show up on the webpage. The table name is forslag_stemmer, and it has its primary key= id, and foreign keys brukerid (the user that votes for a certain person) and foreign key forslagid (this is the people who receives votes from the users).

This query works in workbench, but not on the page:

```
echo "<u><b>Number of votes</u></b>:";

$sql= "SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM 
       bb.forslag_stemmer WHERE forslagid=$forslagid";

$resultat = $kobling->query($sql);

while($rad=$resultat->fetch_assoc())
{
    $forslagid = $rad["forslagid"];

    echo $sql;
    echo "$resultat->num_rows";
}
```

I really don't know what to do?

Comment: you're open to SQL injection and should take carte of that issue immediatly. Also you have quotation marks around your variable echo? this is not needed.. just `echo $foo->num_rows`;

Comment: Thanks, I've edited that now, but still, nothings shows up after "echo"number of votes";. It seems like the query doesn't get through

Comment: If you do `var_dump($rad);` in your while loop do you get something?

Answer (score 2):

You select **one field** `COUNT( * )` as result of your query. There will be **no** other fields in a result.

```
echo "<u><b>Number of votes</u></b>:";
// I added an alias for field
$sql= "SELECT COUNT( * ) as votes_count FROM bb.forslag_stemmer WHERE forslagid=$forslagid";
$resultat = $kobling->query($sql);
$rad = $resultat->fetch_assoc();
// access value by alias
echo $rad['votes_count'];
```

Comment: Now it correctly states the number of votes, however only for one candidate. On the website I have various others, but only one candidate shows up with his votes

Comment: Well, this is what you asked for no? Your question is `Echo number of rows where id=$id` so ofc it show only one user filter by `$id` !

Comment: yes i do, but in my code i've tried to echo all the candidates with their info and their votes as well

Comment: Please, ask another question with __correct__ problem description.

Comment: i have under 10 candidates, each with their own id ofcourse, but i want to show the number of votes (=number of rows where their candidate id has been submittet to the table forslag_stemmer by different users)  on the site

Comment: Then why is the text of the question describes another problem, __why__?

Comment: I formulated myself wrongly, as english isn't my first language. Due to the nature of my not so specific formulation, of course misunderstandings could happen, I'm really sorry!

Comment: Again, __ask another well-formulated question__.

Comment: But what I meant by my question was how I could echo the number of rows where forslagid (candidate that has been receiving votes) had been submitted, to each candidate, so that the number of votes they have been receiving shows up on the page.

Comment: I don't care what you meant, I'm telling you __third time__: ask a __NEW__ question with your real problem, __please__.

Answer (score 0):

> mysqli_result::num_rows Gets the number of rows in a result

In your Example since you're querying as "select count(*) from table" it always returns Number of rows as "1"

You can get Number of rows in two ways

Method 1:

```
$sql= "SELECT * from FROM bb.forslag_stemmer WHERE forslagid=$forslagid";
$result = $con->query($sql);
echo $result->num_rows; // prints number of rows found
```

Method 2:

```
$sql= "SELECT count(*) as resultcount from FROM bb.forslag_stemmer WHERE 
       forslagid=$forslagid";
$result = $con->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo $row['resultcount']; // prints number of rows found
}
```